# Odoo loading javascript files in version 8?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

How do you load javascript files in version 8? In version 7, you could simply show the location of `js` in manifesto file (`__openerp__.py`) like this:

`'js': ['static/src/js/file.js'],`

Now it does not work.

For example I created js file in my module with this code:

```
openerp.calendar_service = function(instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt,
        QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    instance.calendar_service = {};
    console.log('TEST')
};
```

But using debugger, I don't see that `TEST` is printed. If I add such print in some source js files (in other modules), it will print it fine. So how do I make my js files load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the example shown in following:

```
/addons/account/views/account.xml
```

This will show you how to add the javascript and css files to your module.

Answer (score 4):

You have to load your JS file from xml template.

Here you go!

Create one xml file inside views folder and add template record.

your_module>>views>>new_file.xml (This is convention only you can create this record in any xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="unique_template_id" name="String value" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/your_js_file.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```