# How to add css and javascript files to a custom module in Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, odoo

this question has already been answered here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846826/how-to-add-css-files-to-a-custom-module-in-odoo-8#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846826/how-to-add-css-files-to-a-custom-module-in-odoo-8#_=_)

The css link worked but it didn't work with the js link, the server breaks down.

Could you please help!
Here's my code

```
<openerp>
  <data>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="mymodule css assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/islam/static/src/js/javascript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/islam/static/src/css/style.css"/>         
      </xpath>
    </template>   
  </data>
</openerp>
```

PS: this line :  indicates the file where are defined the functions used in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example shown in following:

```
/addons/account/views/account.xml
```

This will show you how to add the javascript and css files to your module.

Comment: I believe that i followed the same example, but i added this link <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> which indicates the library where the js functions are defined.
i think the problem is with the link 
is there any solutions ?

Comment: @Hardik Patadia The same answer is located at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166447/odoo-loading-javascript-files-in-version-8/29166734#29166734

Comment: @Hardik Patadia i work with liclipse to work on modules of odoo and when i  downloaded this link https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js and edit its path in the xml file that you showed me  
it doesn't work in odoo whereas it works normally with browsers.
what do you think ??

Comment: have you got this file physically on your computer? or is it external link?

Comment: it is an external link, from the official website.
Actually i can't figure out where the problem is , and I'm wondering if the syntaxe is valid or not on odoo !
Could you give me please your email or your facebook account in order to communicate more fluently ?


                  
}